# Trying to make my smoke simulation look like this

Tags: smoke-simulation

But not quite with that much speed and force. More so lingering out of the vents

https://youtu.be/wka3sM1cm0s

Answer (score 0):

Never tried to use smoke but I just did it and it's quite easy. you put your object domain. your object flow and then a force-field wind (shift+A). you set all in physics. I put some objects in front with collision on (still in smoke settings) and it's doing some turbulence but you can make change the value of the strength of the wind. you put a first key and then in graph editor in N menu you add noise modifier or something like this to change your value randomly [image]

you can add a vortex force too with a negative strengh to put more mess...
[image]

[image]